# Multiple widget embeds without double loading widget file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any easy solution to the following.
Lets say we are building a embed widget.

The embed code looks like this:

```
<div id="widget_2928282"></div>
<script src="widget.init.js"></script>
```

But lets assume someone does multiple embeds on one page the following way (assume they copy/paste the embed code generated from site)

```
<div class="widget" id="122"></div>
<script src="widget.init.js"></script>

<div class="widget" id="123"></div>
<script src="widget.init.js"></script>

<div class="widget" id="124"></div>
<script src="widget.init.js"></script>
```

I know you could probably tell people to only include it 1 time, but we never know if people follow it, we can't assume they do.

Now the widget.init.js gets included 3 times. But in the widget init file we run a for each to loop through the divs with the widget class, but offcourse we don't want to run this 6 times and also we don't want to include the widget.init.js file more then once, since we only need it 1 time.

Is there any smart way to filter out any unnecessary includes once the first widget init file is called.. so we always only load the widget init file just one time?

Could we just do something like this?

```
var countScriptEmbeds = 0;
countScriptEmbeds++;

if (countScriptEmbeds == 1) {
// execute our script
}
```

Or something in that direction?....
Thank you.